# Understanding a very trivial combinatorics question

Tags: combinatorics

I have found a huge gap in my knowledge of understanding very very easy combinatorics problems.

Can somebody explain the following:

A person has 4 sweaters, 2 t-sirts and 3 trausers. In how many ways can a person get dressed ?

The answer is : $4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 24$ if it is necessary that he wears exactly one sweater

The other answer is: $5 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 = 30$ if the above is not necessary.

I would need explanation of the first and specially the second answer.

Comment: The change from $4$ to $5$ is when he is allowed to wear no sweater...

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I see, that was what troubled me

Comment: First answer - pick one of the shirts, one of the trousers and one of the sweaters. How many ways to choose a shirt for example? Second answer - it seems that the person does not wear a sweater or wears _one_. So $4$ ways to choose a sweater and $5th$ option is no sweater.

Comment: @MathLover So if he would not need to wear any of the clothing, then we would have $5\cdot 4 \cdot 3$ right ?

Comment: yes that is correct